# GRUB and GPT configuration and backup for Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, grub, gpt

I'm considering dual booting Windows 10 with Ubuntu on an [Acer Aspire E laptop](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/CA/content/model/NX.MLFAA.003).  What utilities can I use to view the boot configuration *prior* to installing Ubuntu?  Is that with `bcdedit`?  [This article looks ok](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/bcdedit-basics), but not sure it's relevant for Windows 10.

When I install Ubuntu it will write GRUB using/to GPT?  It looks like the super GRUB disk is useful for troubleshooting this issue.

What is the interplay between Windows 10 booting through GPT with GRUB?

I want at least view the configurations to write them down, if not store them for backup before proceeding.

Based on the [how to geek article about GPT](http://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/), and that the laptop runs UEFI I believe Windows 10 is almost certainly booting with GPT.  If not, I'll ask a separate question.

Comment: Are you using a Guided partiton Table , GPT?

Comment: @GAD3R The updated question specifies GPT.  Thanks.